# How do I convert OnCollisionEnter2D to OnMouseDown?

Tags: collision-detection, mouse

I created a simple animation.

I have a `"Gamer"` object, which I move and hit squares to destroy them.

Squares I have to destroy in the right order `(1-2-3-4-5 etc.)`

If I make a mistake, the animation comes to an end.

However, I would like to change this code now. I would like to change `OnCollisionEnter2D()` on `OnMouseDown()`.

I would like to continue to delete the squares one by one, but instead of using a collision - simply click on the squares.

Could anyone help you convert this code?

This is my code posted to the `"Gamer"` object:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Gamer : MonoBehaviour {

    int index =1;
    public GameObject gameOverText, restartButton ;

    public GameObject WinningText, ExitButton, NextLevelButton ;

    public GameObject Manager;


    void Start () {
        gameOverText.SetActive (false);
        restartButton.SetActive (false);
        Manager.SetActive (true);
        WinningText.SetActive (false);
        ExitButton.SetActive (false);
        NextLevelButton.SetActive (false);
    }
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player hit object: " + col.transform.name);
        //check if the object you hit is one of the "collisionObjects":
        if(col.transform.GetComponent<collisionObject>())
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        {
            collisionObject colObj = col.transform.GetComponent<collisionObject>();
            if(!colObj) return;
            if(index == colObj.myIndexNumber) {
                if (colObj.isHighestNumber) {
                    Debug.Log ("Yay you correctly hit the last Square, You WIN!");
                    WinningText.SetActive (true);
                    NextLevelButton.SetActive (true);
                    ExitButton.SetActive (true);
                    gameObject.SetActive (false);
                    Manager.SetActive (false);
                }
                Destroy(col.gameObject);
                index++;

            }
            // here, we know it didn't match the number. :)
            else  {
                gameOverText.SetActive (true);
                restartButton.SetActive (true);
                gameObject.SetActive (false);
                Manager.SetActive (false);

            }
        }    
    }
}
```

And this is my code placed in the `"square"` object:

```
        using System.Collections;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using UnityEngine;

        public class collisionObject : MonoBehaviour {
           public int myIndexNumber;
           public bool isHighestNumber;
           public void Start()
           {

        isHighestNumber = true;
        //find all other objects:
        foreach (collisionObject cObj in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<collisionObject>()) {

            //check if any of the other objects has a larger number than mine, if yes, note to self that i am not the highest number.
            if (cObj.myIndexNumber > myIndexNumber) {
                isHighestNumber = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Object number " + myIndexNumber + " is here // is highest Number: " + isHighestNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit the object on which you want to detect mouse click with [EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) and move your code from `OnCollisionEnter2D` to `void OnPointerClick()`

You'll need to add `PhysicsRaycaster` component on the camera to detect mouseovers/clicks

Answer (score 0):

Move the `OnMouseDown` function to the `square` objects. Inside of it, call something like `gamer.ClickedSquare(myIndexNumber);` where `gamer` is your hero (I assume). Note that you should give a reference of the `gamer` to each `square` for this to work.

Then on the `Gamer` class, convert your `OnCollisionEnter2D(...)` with `ClickedSquare(int index)` (or any other name you want to give it). This function will be called every time a square is clicked, and give it's index number, then it's up to the `gamer` object to decide if the index is the expected one, or to ignore it if it's the wrong one.